# SilverStripe change field label from parent class

Tags: php, silverstripe

Within `SiteConfig` there is a `TextField` *Site title*. I'm trying to change the label of this textfield `$titleField` through a **SiteConfig extension** in class `SiteConfigExtension extends DataExtension`.

Here is the code from *siteconfig/code/model/* where it's created:

```
$fields = new FieldList(
    new TabSet("Root",
        $tabMain = new Tab('Main',
            $titleField = new TextField("Title", _t('SiteConfig.SITETITLE', "Site title")),
                ....
```

Q: What's the easiest way to replace the SiteTitle label without having to remove the field in the SiteConfig extension and re-add it again with the desired label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the title from SiteConfigExtension uses updateCMSFields...

```
class SiteConfigExtension extends DataExtension {

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        if ($titleField = $fields->dataFieldByName('Title'))
            $titleField->setTitle('my title');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Barry. `$titleField` is set within a method within class `SiteTree`. How could I change the value of $titleField in a child class, let's say `Page` which `extends SiteTree`.

Comment: I did test it in a clean install - can you update your question to be a "minimum amount to replicate" given the case of updating the Title from SiteTree in Page and you should find it to work... or maybe if your example is clearer I'll see where I need to update this to make it work...

Comment: My first comment to this answer is incorrect, sorry for confusion. I'm actually trying to change the label within an extension class of SiteConfig: `SiteConfigExtension extends DataExtension`, so SiteTree is not involved.

Comment: That did it! I suggest removing the upper part of the answer to have an answer that matches the question without clutter. Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118133/discussion-between-faloude-and-barry).

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the implemented `_t()` function. Put following in your `mysite/lang/{LANG_CODE}.yml` file:

```
{LANG_CODE}:
  SiteConfig:
    SITETITLE: 'My new title'
```

Replace `{LANG_CODE}` with the admin language(s) being used (eg `sv` for Swedish, or `en` for English). Keeping your strings separated from the code comes with many benefits. Remember to run `?flush` after updating YAML files.

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/i18n/

Comment: Ah yes, clever. However, the default value for the `_t()` would still be hardcoded in `class SiteTree` thus showing the original label in the default locale or when no translation is defined.

Comment: You're right, one drawback would be if there were many admins on different locales, then you'd have to define the string for each locale. However even when in the default locale site defined lang files take priority afaik. I think it goes `site lang file` > `module lang file` > `default string` > `field name`